# Static Objects and Seed Data in EF Code-First

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Beginner question here.  Given the following:

```
        public static Tenant Www = new Tenant() { TenantId = 1, Name = "www", Urls = new string[]{"https://app.com"}};
```

I have a reference to an object with the parameters defined.  In this case, is it assumed that the object with these values exists in the database?

My seed method contains the following:

```
 if (context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Www") == null) {
            context.Tenants.Add(new Tenant() {
                TenantId = 1,
                Name = "Www",
                Urls = new string[]{"https://app.com", "http://localhost"}
            });
        }
```

Note that the Tenant from my Seed method contains an extra `Url`.  I'm confused about which version gets used when querying via `Tenant.Www`.

If I use the static method via something like `obj.TenantId = Tenant.Www.TenantId`, I get that only the Id is used, but what if I do something like `obj.Tenants.push(Tenant.Www)`?  Which one gets used, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it assumed that the object with these values exists in the database

No, it's just an instance of `Tenant` class. There's nothing about persistence of this object in the given line of code.

> I'm confused about which version gets used when querying via

Your `Seed` method will try to get `Tenant`, which `Name` equals `"Www"`.
If such record will be found in database, EF will materialize new `Tenant` object and populate its properties by values from database. From the point of CLR, `Tenant.Www` and that newly materialized object will be different object. In other words,

```
context.Tenants.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Www") != Tenant.Www
```

> Which one gets used, and why?

Again, `obj != Tenant.Www`.
There's no magic in EF. When you call constructor of entity type, you just create new object. EF context knows nothing about your objects, until you tell about them via `Add`/`Attach` methods.

**UPDATE**.

If you want some default `Tenant` instance, then:
1) throw away your static instance;
2) define criteria for searching default instance (e.g., `Name == "Www"`);
3) when you need this default instance, just query it from database by the criteria, defined above.

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  If I'm just trying to use a static class for shortcut's sake, would it be safe to define an instance of Tenant with ONLY TenantId defined, so I can always assign relationships via Tenant.Www.TenantId?  Or would you suggest always performing that FirstOrDefault query to be safe?

Comment: Define "safety" in your question's context, please. What do you want this static instance for at all?

Comment: With my id-defined approach, I'd be afraid of assigning empty or stale Tenant objects should I ever perform an operation like push(Tenant.Www) or Add(Tenant.Www).  Eg: Suppose the static Tenant.Www only has an Id defined, and I use it in an Add() operation, will another Tenant be created because EF couldn't find an exact match?  Or will the Tenant from Seed() with the matching Id be used because EF only cares about PKs?

Comment: The `Add()` operation would fail, as entity framework would be trying to take a previously unknown object and create a database item for it, and would receive an insert failure in SQL due to a duplicate `Id` Entity Framework **does not** perform a search for a match during an `Add()` operation.

Comment: `Add` just tells the EF context: "look, here's an object with data, that doesn't exists in database. Please, generate `INSERT` query, when I'll call `SaveChanges`". The result depends on existence of the data with the same key in database and key's auto-incrementing policy. Do you want to define some default `Tenant`?

Comment: @AndrewCounts and Dennis - I'm sorry, I meant Add on another object that has a Tenants property.  The duplicate Id when Adding to the DB makes total sense to me, thank you for explaining that case.  Dennis - I am trying to define a default tenant, whose Urls property may change in the Db.  I'm trying to avoid having to update all static objects' properties when they change in the db.